# Use of functions in Facebook's JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, onload, authentication

I got the Facebook login/logout functionality to work, but had to do it with this un-elegant code like this:

```html
<script type="javascript">
    function loadfb() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    };
</script>

<body onload="loadfb()">
```

I plan on putting that Facebook login button on all the pages of the site, so I really don't want to have this function called onload of every page.

Is this function necessary? I don't completely understand what it is for.  What is a better way to do this so I can take it out of my onload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code is for asynchronous loading of the Facebook JavaScript SDK. What it does is create the tag

```html
<script async scr="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js" ></script>
```

inside the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` element. While loading the SDK asynchronously is considered better practice, you can leave out this code and manually enter the script tag yourself - eg:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    ...
  });
</script>
```